# Code to replace or remove existing fragment on backstack not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the `Actionbar` and I have an icon in the appbar which when clicked should go to `CategoryFragment`. But I want to make it so that if that fragment is already on the backstack, it should either remove it and then add a new instance of `CategoryFragment` to the backstack or replace it.

I tried the code below, but it does not work and only overlays/superimposes another copy of `CategoryFragment` on top of the existing `CategoryFragment` and also produces very odd and unexpected behaviors. I'm not using the navcontroller to navigate to `CategoryFragment` since it adds another copy of the fragment in the backstack. How can I make this work?

**onOptionsItemSelected() in Main Activity:**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnOptionsItemSelected() called")

         when (item.itemId) {
                android.R.id.home -> {
                        onBackPressed()
                        return true
                }

               R.id.categoryFragment -> {

                    var backStateName = CategoryFragment::class.simpleName

                    var fragmentPopped = supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0)

                    if(!fragmentPopped)
                    {
                        var ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                        //also tried R.id.main_activity_container which is not working
                        ft.replace(R.id.navHostFragment, CategoryFragment())

                        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName)
                        ft.commit()
                    }

                    return true
                }
    return true
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

        private lateinit var navController: NavController

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnCreate() called")

            navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)

            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.graph)
                .build()
        }

        override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

    super.onSupportNavigateUp()

            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        }

        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnCreateOptionsMenu() called")

            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

            Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnOptionsItemSelected() called")
 when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                    onBackPressed()
                    return true
            }

  R.id.categoryFragment -> {

                var backStateName = CategoryFragment::class.simpleName

                var fragmentPopped = supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0)

                if(!fragmentPopped)
                {
                    var ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                    //also tried R.id.main_activity_container which is not working
                    ft.replace(R.id.navHostFragment, CategoryFragment())

                    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName)
                    ft.commit()
                }

            }

           return true
        }
return true
}
```

**Navgraph:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/categoriesFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/clockFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.ClockFragment"
        android:label="Pomo Clock"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_clock" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoryFragment"
        android:label="Category"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_open_category_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/categoryFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_clockFragment"
            app:destination="@id/clockFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoryFragment_to_newTaskDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newTaskDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/categoriesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.CategoriesFragment"
        android:label="Categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_categories">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_newCategoryDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newCategoryDialogFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            app:argType="com.example.pomoplay.Category" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_categoriesFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromNewCategoryDialog"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newCategoryDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewCategoryDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_category_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newCategoryDialogFragment_to_categoriesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoriesFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/newTaskDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.pomoplay.ui.main.NewTaskDialogFragment"
        android:label="fragment_new_task_dialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_task_dialog" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newTaskDialogFragment_to_categoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/categoryFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/categoryFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `NavController` and therefore you should not be doing any manual `FragmentTransaction`s at all.

Instead, you should [Navigation to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate), in this case, by using Navigation's support for [popUpTo](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) to pop your CategoryFragment off the stack.

Assuming you have a destination set up in your navigation XML for your `CategoryFragment` with code such as:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/categoryFragment"
    android:name=".CategoryFragment/>
```

You can [create an action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#navoptions) that includes the `popUpTo` flag you need (you'd put this directly below the `<fragment>` itself:

```
<action
    android:id+"@+id/open_category"
    app:popUpTo="@id/categoryFragment"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"
    app:destination="@id/categoryFragment"/>
```

This says:

1. Create an action named `open_category`
2. When you trigger this action, pop the stack back up to `categoryFragment` if it already exists on the back stack (otherwise, this does nothing). The `popUpToInclusive` means that the previous instance is popped.
3. After you pop the previous instance, create a new instance of `categoryFragment` and add it to your back stack.

Then you can trigger that action from your `onOptionsItemSelected()'`:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    Log.i("Lifecycle-Activity", "OnOptionsItemSelected() called")

    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.categoryFragment -> {
            // Trigger the action
            navController.navigate(R.id.open_category);
            true
       }
       default -> {
           // android.R.id.home is handled by the call to super,
           // you do not need to handle it here.
           super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your instructions exactly, but when I click the appbar menu icon, the app crashes with this error message: ```navigation destination com.example.pomoplay:id/action_open_category_fragment is unknown to this NavController```. What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems like your solution only works if the current visible fragment is ```CategoryFragment```. If the current visible fragment is a different fragment, then clicking the menu icon in the ```ActionBar``` causes the app to crash with this error message: ```navigation destination com.example.pomoplay:id/action_open_category_fragment is unknown to this NavController```

Comment: Seems like you put the action *within* the `<fragment>` tag, not below it. They should be on the same level

Comment: That's how I have it. I put the action below it. after the ```/>``` closing tag for the ```<fragment>```. But, it still crashes with that error message.

Comment: Can you include your navigation XML in your question?

Comment: I just added the navgraph XML to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, your `<action>` is within the `<fragment>` tag. It should be a direct child of the top level `<navigation>` element as a [global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action). You shouldn't be writing separate actions under each destination.

Comment: Ok. That works. I'll look into learning more about global actions. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "You shouldn't be writing separate actions under each destination."? That's how Android Studio structured the NavGraph XML when I added the actions in the NavGraph visual designer. So, should all my actions be global instead of being child elements of their respective parent fragments as the IDE structured it?

Comment: If you want an action to be available from all destinations (hence, the name a global action), then the global action page shows how to do that in the visual designer. If you want an action to only link two destinations (i.e., you click a button in one screen to go to the next), then you'd use a regular action. For global actions like those from your activity's menu, you'd want to choose a global action. More about picking the right tool for what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Just one last question. The way we have this setup, the ActionBar menu icon click causes a "Pop To" to the ```CategoryFragment``` and also removes its duplicate on the back stack if it already exists. But this is causing all fragments above this popped ```CategoryFragment``` in the back stack to be popped off also. Hence, I can't go back to those fragments when I click on the Up arrow on the ActionBar or the physical back button on the phone. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The back stack is indeed a [stack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) - you can only pop things off the top of the stack. There's a `launchSingleTop` that you can use instead of `popUpTo` if you instead only want just one copy on the top of the stack and don't worry about instances farther back on the stack.

Comment: Is there a way to remove all instances of the ```CategoryFragment``` on the back stack before adding a new instance to it to the top?

Comment: Only if you remove everything between the top of the stack and the `CategoryFragment` instances, which is what `popUpTo` does.

Comment: Ok, I thought as much. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what I meant was, can I remove all instances of ```CategoryFragment``` from the back stack while leaving all other fragments on the stack intact? I'm inferring from what you said that this is not possible. I'll have to settle for the ```popUpTo``` option. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible. That's why I linked to the definition of what a stack is, which makes it clear that those types of modifications on anything but the top of the stack would not be possible.